# How to measure HTTP performance from Java / Android (no curl)

Tags: java, android

We use OkHttp library to make API call (http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

We are looking for a solution using Java to measure the following response time (linked to http protocol):

- DNS Lookup
- TCP Connection
- Content Generation
- Content Transfer

Until now, we did not find how to do it using Java. Any ideas ?

Comment: Google for "java web performance testing tools".  You will find things like JMeter, The Grinder, and so on.

Comment: We need to embed it in our own code and will not use a third party tool.

Comment: In that case, you have a lot of coding to do .... and your question is too broad.

Comment: We did the same with Go and Python and it was straightforward as http client librairies let you access to raw timing of http protocol. In java it seems not the case... so sad.

Answer (score 0):

For Http logs. Use HttpLoggingInterceptor to see Response time and Logs.

Gradle for Interceptor :

```
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

Code for Logging in OkHTTP

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
// set your desired log level

    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(20, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();
```

I think you were looking for this Only

Check out for More Logging Info:

Read Wiki:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: We saw this method, but from the interceptor, how could we get those response time ? (Like curl in fact)

Comment: It show the time for getting data get back in Millis after the URL. I dont have knowledge about curl. how the response time looks like.